# SQL find latest date if mentioned date is not found and extend output

Tags: sql, plsql

For my example, I need to do a **procedure** that calculates the balance on the **desired date** for the **selected batch**.

If there is **no balance for the date entered**, **it finds and calculates the balance for the last existing date**.

I have tried something like this:

```
select saldo_do, saldo_br
from
trr_extracts
where batch = 135 and dat_extr = '21.3.2019';
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT dat_extr, max(dat_extr)
from trr_extracts
where batch = 135
group by dat_extr;

SELECT IFNULL(dat_extr('21.3.2023'), max(dat_extr)
FROM trr_extracts;
```

The problem is, **how to write a statement which returns only one of parameters (saldo_do or saldo_br) and finds the last date from batch that is given**.

**EXPLANATION:**

The **saldo_do** is (positive account balance currency) while **saldo_br** is (negative account balance currency). The account can only have one. (it can be in plus or in minus with currency balance).

**If I run this code:**

```
select saldo_do, saldo_br
from
trr_extracts
where batch = 135 and dat_extr = '21.3.2019';
```

**The result is:**

[image]

This account has positive balance. Because of positive balance it should just print saldo_do WITHOUT saldo_br. Like this.

[image]

**If negative**, then It should only print saldo_br.

**For now**, I want to print only one result. **Positive** if the account is in positive. **Negative** if account is negative.

**THE NEXT PROBLEM IS:**

if the entered date in the example above ('21.3.2019') **DOES NOT EXIST** for the **given batch of (135)**, the statement then **should find the LAST date of batch 135** and use that date insted.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: You tagged PLSQL, but used `IFNULL`. Use  `nvl(argument1, argument2)` instead. You also might need a subquery for `argument1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some information. Example data from your table and the expected results always help.
Here is the best I could do with the information given.

```
with data(saldo_do, saldo_br,batch,dat_extr) as (
select 1,2,135,'21.3.2019' a from dual union all
select 1,2,135,'21.5.2019' a from dual union all
select 1,2,135,'21.4.2019' a from dual union all
select 1,2,135,'21.4.2019' a from dual
)
select sum(saldo_do) saldo_do,sum(saldo_br) saldo_br,max(dat_extr) dat_extr from data
where batch = 135 and dat_extr != '21.3.2019' 
group by dat_extr
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82737f99ae14e23d8aa2a66ad6b7e619

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the explanation above so It is more clear to understand. The problem is quite complicated. The query has to return only one (saldo_do or saldo_br) depending on the accounts balance (positive or negative) AND should use LAST DATE for the batch 135, if input date (21.3.2019) CANT return data. (For this example, sure batch 135 and date 21.3.2019 return something, but if not then query uses last date). I ve tried with MAX, nullif and other, but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data(saldo_do, saldo_br,batch,dat_extr) as (
select 1,-5,135,'21.3.2019' a from dual union all
select 2,-6,135,'21.5.2019' a from dual union all
select 3,-7,135,'21.4.2019' a from dual union all
select 4,-8,135,'21.4.2019' a from dual
),
maxPbatch as (
select saldo_do, saldo_br,batch,dat_extr
from data where batch = 135 
and dat_extr = 
(select  max(dat_extr) dat_extr 
from data 
where batch = 135 and dat_extr != '21.3.2019'
group by batch )
)
select 
case when d.dat_extr is null then m.saldo_do else d.saldo_do end saldo_do
,case when d.dat_extr is null then m.saldo_br else d.saldo_br end saldo_br
,case when d.dat_extr is null then m.dat_extr else d.dat_extr end dat_extr

from maxPbatch m
left join data d on d.batch = m.batch
and d.dat_extr = '21.3.2019'
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a1bd0e23c5b1afb4e7a86566aa4d4d6